# Use an image as cursor with laravel project

Tags: css, laravel, image, mouse-cursor

I would like to see an image as cursor if the pointer is inside a div.

This is my code:

**FileController.php**

```
public function addMarkClientFile(File $file)
{
        $imagePath = asset('/img/mark-facsimile.png');
        return view("documents.addMark", compact("imagePath"));
}
```

**addMark.blade.php**

```
@extends('layout.master')
@section('style')
    @parent
    <style>
        .canvas-with-cursor {
            cursor: url('{{ $imagePath }}'), crosshair !important;
        }
    </style>
@stop
@section('content')
....
<div class="canvas-with-cursor" id="pdf-preview"></div>
...
@stop
```

But I don't see the image but the 'crosshair' as fallback.
I also tried with an image get from an url on the web, and it works, so I think it is a problem with my url.

The image is located into `/public/img/` folder.

If I debug it into the browser I get this "http://site.loc:9080/img/mark-facsimile.png" and trying to open the url, I can get the image without issue.

I also tried to change `asset('/img/mark-facsimile.png')` with `url('/img/mark-facsimile.png')` but it doesn't change.

Comment: Have you tried `url({{ $imagePath }})` (without the quotes)?

Comment: @brombeer yes, same issue.

Comment: whats the css you can see in the developer tools from the browser? does it show correctly?

Comment: @TomasLucena yes it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hey I think I found what the issues is:

> Icon size limits While the specification does not limit the cursor
> image size, user agents commonly restrict them to avoid potential
> misuse. For example, on Firefox and Chromium cursor images are
> restricted to 128x128 pixels by default, but it is recommended to
> limit the cursor image size to 32x32 pixels. Cursor changes using
> images that are larger than the user-agent maximum supported size will
> generally just be ignored.

Your code works! I have tested on my own Laravel application and had the same issue, then I reduced the dimensions of the cursor image and it worked fine!

Hope it helps!